# How do I detect malware and remove it from iPad?

Tags: ipad, malware

I was an idiot, clicked on a zip file from a scam (notice to appearing court). How do I know if the malware did in fact get installed and if it did, how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 6):

You haven't got malware on your iPad. To extract zip files, you need a third-party app and this app's data will be contained within the sandbox of that app.